# Visual Studio 2010 Ultamate Hangs at 100% compile for more than 3 minutes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When I am trying to debug (F5) in visual studio the compile hits 100% and sits there and takes forever to start my program that I want to debug. Also when the program does start it takes just as long for the program to close and the Visual Studio to start responding. Does anyone know why this happens?

- Project is C# wpf, I use to have a silverlight project that did the same thing. I moved all the code to a new project and now my silverlight project works better now.
- No special debug option, the same options that come with a new project.
- The project is on the local C drive hooked up to TFS 2010.
- No Static Analysis or ReSharper that I know of.
- My Solution has 14 projects in it. 1 wpf and the rest are dll's and tool exe's.
- No Anti-malware, and I disabled antivirus just to make sure it wasn't eating my lunch.
- I unplugged my network cable and that did not help any of the network timeouts.
- Disable any symbol servers Did not help.

Comment: These kind of long delays are almost always associated with networking timeouts.  There's one for the debugger: Tools + Options, Debugging, Symbols.  Disable any symbol servers listed there and try again.  Anti-malware is the next likely troublemaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that if you delete the .SUO file that things get fast it has been removed. It is next to your .sln file. My .suo file was 4.5 mb.

- From Google all I can find is that the .suo file is some kind of user settings file but doesn't seem to do any harm when deleted, it just gets recreated.
- Found that when doing an import on settings you can get your .suo file to go up in size... the size of the .suo file might not be the issue however a corrupted one might be the issue. I imported setting and made my .suo file go up to 5.7mb and my compile works ok, I deleted it however again because I don't want it to get corrupted.

Comment: That's interesting information. However, we folks like to understand stuff! Could you perhaps describe the project/solution a bit in the question? (Aside from the fact that it is C#) Any special things about debug configuration? Debug options? Is the project stored locally or on a network drive? Are you using source control (plugins)? Are you using static analysis? Are you using ReSharper or others? Perhaps someone might think of the actual reason etc.

Comment: my class library solution with 10 projects builds quite fast with a 1.2Mb suo file.